# Exclude an item from a table but take it's attributes (quantity, weight, price) and add it onto an item in a new table (complete details shown)

Tags: sql, vb.net

For this example, a user can select one or more package from a checklistbox that is populated with packages. The packages info is stored in the packageHeaderTable. A Package or packages are made for a customer. PackageID is PK of this table (packageHeaderTable) and autoincrements for every new package being sold. The packageHeaderTable looks like this with sample data of 3 packages (there are hundreds):

```
PackageID | Weight | TotalPrice 
-------------------------------
 1        | 12.5   | $24.00 
-------------------------------
 2        | 15.0   | $26.00       
-------------------------------
 3        | 17.5   | $28.00
```

A Package hold several items. Each item has attributes such as weight, price, Quantity, Item Description. This table is called PackageLineTable. Note that ItemId is the PK of this table while PackageID is the PK, FK of this table coming from PackageHeaderTable

```
ItemID | PackageID | ItemDesc  | Weight| Price  | Quantity|
----------------------------------------------------------
1      | 1         |  ball     | 2.5   | 2.00   |  1
----------------------------------------------------------
2      | 1         |  bat      | 7.0   | 15.00  |  2
----------------------------------------------------------
3      | 1         |  glove    | 3.0   | 7.00   |  1
----------------------------------------------------------
1      | 2         |  ball     | 2.5   | 2.00   |  3
----------------------------------------------------------
2      | 2         |  bat      | 7.0   | 15.00  |  3
----------------------------------------------------------
3      | 2         |  glove    | 3.0   | 7.00   |  1
----------------------------------------------------------
1      | 3         |  ball     | 2.5   | 2.00   |  4
----------------------------------------------------------
2      | 3         |  bat      | 7.0   | 15.00  |  3
----------------------------------------------------------
3      | 3         |  glove    | 3.0   | 7.00   |  1
----------------------------------------------------------
```

Now I have to make a BallBatPackage Table and create a report that uses this table which excludes the item 'gloves' in every package but still takes the gloves weight and price and adds it onto the first ball's weight and price that is in the customer's order of packages.

BallBatReportHeaderTable    (PackageId is FK from PackageLineTable)

```
ReportID (PK) | PackageID (PK,Fk) | Weight | TotalPrice 
-------------------------------------------------------
 1            | 1                 | 12.5   | $24.00 
-------------------------------------------------------
 1            | 2                 | 15.0   | $26.00      
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Report/Table I have to create needs to look like this:

BallBatReportLineTable

```
ReportID(PK,FK) | ItemID (PK)  | PackageID (Pk,FK) | ItemDesc  | Weight| Price  | Quantity|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        1        |     1       | 1                 |  ball     | 8.5   | 16.00  |  3
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        1        |     2       | 1                 |  bat      | 7.0   | 15.00  |  2
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        1        |     1       | 2                 |  ball     | 2.5   | 2.00   |  3
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        1        |     2       | 2                 |  bat      | 7.0   | 15.00  |  3
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Note that the two gloves that were in the customer's two packages (PackageID 1 and Package ID 2) that were ordered are gone but it's weight, price, and quantity got added onto the first ball on the list of items in the two packages.

I am having a hard time figuring out how to create this table and have it do what I need it to do with the ball and gloves. This is what I've tried so far to deal with it's quantity but it's not working right. (I am just working with Quantity for now). I have in front of me the packages the customer ordered and am checking the packages that he ordered on the chkLstPackages (checklistbox) and clicking add Packages (cmdAddPackages) to the DGVBallBatReport to basically view the table right after it gets created. I need to do this SQL update and have it work somehow but it isn't doing what I need and I'm just getting lost and confused:

```
 Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("UPDATE BallBatLineTable SET Quantity = (BallBatLineTable.Quantity + (Select sum(Quantity) FROM PackageLineTable WHERE PackageID = @PackageID and ItemID Like 'Glove'))", con)

        For i As Integer = 0 To chkLstPackages.Items.Count - 1
            If chkLstShipments.GetItemCheckState(i) = CheckState.Checked Then
                If isFirst = True Then
                  cmd.Commandtext += " Where PackageID = @PackageID" + i.toString
                    isFirst = False
                Else
                  cmd.CommandText += " OR PackageID = @PackageID + i.toString
                End If
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@PackageID" + i.ToString, SqlDbType.Int).Value = chkLstPackages.Items(i)
            End If           
       Next
```

Comment: Does no one understand the question? Or is it just that no one wants to take the time to read through all this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are creating new tables for reporting things. To create reports you should just be using regular queries based off your PackageLineTable.

So for package total:

```
select
packageid,
sum(weight * quantity) [weight],
sum(price * quantity) [price]
from packagelinetable
group by packageid
```

To add the total of the "gloves" item to the first item in a package of a different type:

You can do a sub-select, that takes all rows that are "gloves" and replaces the itemdesc with another item description. After that do a group by query where everything is added together:

```
select
packageid,
itemdesc,
sum(weight * quantity) [weight],
sum(price * quantity) [price]
from (select
    packageid,
    weight,
    price,
    quantity,
    case itemdesc
    when 'glove'
    then (select top 1 itemdesc from packagelinetable i where i.packageid = p.packageid and i.itemdesc <> 'glove' order by itemdesc)
    else itemdesc end [itemdesc]
    from packagelinetable p) as sub
group by packageid, itemdesc
```

Comment: I need to keep the first table with the record of the gloves in packagelineTable. I don't want to switch it out there.  I need the switching out done in the BallBatLineTable because it's what the report calls for.

Comment: Edited: You can just select the first item description from the package that is not a glove

Comment: Are you trying to make changes to the PackageLineTable? I can't be making changes to that table, that is live data. I have to make my own table that is basically a duplicate to use for reporting to swap out gloves and add it's attributes to another item in the package with it.

Comment: It is a select statement, so it is a read-only query. I don't think there is any need for new tables for reporting

Comment: ah ok gotcha. The report table is so that report data is stored in case someone needs to look at a report made a year ago or a week ago..